# Can Pax Web Whiteboard ResourceMapping have path pointing outside the bundle?

Tags: pax, pax-web

I've tried to register the following `ResourceMapping` as an OSGi service:

```
package ru.focusmedia.odp.server.poim.http;

import org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.ResourceMapping;

import ru.focusmedia.odp.server.poim.api.PoimConfig;

import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Component;

@Component(immediate = true)
public class PoimResourceMapping implements ResourceMapping {
    private String httpContextId;
    private String alias = "...";
    private String someAbsolutePath = "...";

    @Override
    public String getHttpContextId() {
        return httpContextId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAlias() {
        return "/resources";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return someAbsolutePath;
    }

}
```

but don't see the result in browser under `http://127.0.0.1:8282/resources/aFileUnderMyPath`. I can see that Pax Web is accessing my mapping in the log. Is this possible or do I need to write a servlet instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The `path` is resolved relative to the bundle and therefore your absolute path will turn in some url syntax error.

Why not loading your file in a bundle and serving it from there? We dynamically load bundles with resources that we need to serve following some versioning conventions.

Comment: That's a possibility, but not too convenient. For an administrator, there is quite a bit of difference between "put a file into this directory" and "put a file into this directory, then rebuild the bundle and deploy it". Similarly, I'd need to restart the bundle whenever a user uploads a document...

Comment: Yes, depends on your usecase of course. In our case, the files to serve are produced by the build, so it's a natural integration. In your case, where you want to serve files dropped-in by users, you'd need to look into a servlet made for that purpose.